# angularjs multiple resolve with loadsequence and auth permission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication

Referring to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431797/angularjs-multiple-resolve), I am having the same problem.

How can we set up a multiple resolve, one with **currentAuth** and another with **loadsequence** which loads controllers and scripts?

Here is my `state config` :

```
.state('app.example', {
        url: "/example",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/example.html",
        resolve:{
            loadSequence: loadSequence('jquery-sparkline', 'exampleCtrl')
        },
        title: 'example',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'example'
        }
    })
```

and here is my `loadsequece` function:

```
function loadSequence() {
    var _args = arguments;
    return {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q',
        function ($ocLL, $q) {
            var promise = $q.when(1);
            for (var i = 0, len = _args.length; i < len; i++) {
                promise = promiseThen(_args[i]);
            }
            return promise;

            function promiseThen(_arg) {
                if (typeof _arg == 'function')
                    return promise.then(_arg);
                else
                    return promise.then(function () {
                        var nowLoad = requiredData(_arg);
                        if (!nowLoad)
                            return $.error('Route resolve: Bad resource name [' + _arg + ']');
                        return $ocLL.load(nowLoad);
                    });
            }

            function requiredData(name) {
                if (jsRequires.modules)
                    for (var m in jsRequires.modules)
                        if (jsRequires.modules[m].name && jsRequires.modules[m].name === name)
                            return jsRequires.modules[m];
                return jsRequires.scripts && jsRequires.scripts[name];
            }
        }]
    };
}
```

and here is my `currentAuth` factory:

```
currentAuth: ['Auth', function(Auth) {
                return Auth.$requireSignIn()
            }]
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation of ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) :

> The resolve property is a map object. The map object contains key/value pairs of:
>
> key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.
>
> factory - {string|function}:
> If string, then it is an alias for a service.
> Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a promise, it is resolved before the controller is instantiated and its value is injected into the controller.

so you can configure your state adding functions in your state resolve :

```
.state('app.example', {
    url: "/example",
    templateUrl: "assets/views/example.html",
     resolve: { 
scripts: loadSequence('jquery-sparkline', 'exampleCtrl').deps,
currentAuth: function(Auth){ return Auth.$requireSignIn();}
},
    title: 'example',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'example'
    }
})
```

Comment: This works, but I'm still unable to access `currentAuth` from the controller. What am I missing?

Comment: @IvanCarosati Check your controller definition, you need to add currentAuth as argument of controller function. controller: function($scope, currentAuth){$scope.auth = currentAuth;}

Comment: I turned out that the controller has to be declared within the routes. I was using ng-controller and that execute the resolves but doesn't inject the resolved dependencies! Hope it help others landing on this page!